# MS SQL specific ordering

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-order-by

My english won't help to explain what my problem is but i will give a try.

Lets say we have a table with (photoId, _bandId, desc)

Now we have a set of records

```
1, 1000, TestDesc1 
2, 1000, TestDesc2 
3, 1010, TestDesc3 
4, 1900, TestDesc4 
5, 1000, TestDesc5
```

Im trying to find a select command where gets all the [desc] for a specific [_bandId]
BUT AS FIRST RESULT i want a specific photoId

What i use,

```
SELECT * FROM [myTable]
WHERE _bandId = (SELECT _bandId from [myTable] where photoId=2)
```

This of course gives me as output :

```
TestDesc1 
TestDesc2 
TestDesc5
```

BUT what i really need as output is this

```
TestDesc2 
TestDesc1 
TestDesc5
```

Kind Regards
Konstantinos

Comment: What is the ordering condition?

Comment: Hello, This is what i am trying to find i want as first result row the given photoId (in my example is 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `order by` with a `case` as the first parameter, where you create a value that is 0 for the record that you want first and 1 for the other records. After that you can add more parameters for how you want to sort the remaing records, for example on description:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  [myTable]
WHERE
  _bandId = (SELECT _bandId from [myTable] where photoId=2)
ORDER BY
  CASE PhotoId WHEN 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  [desc]
```